# Accessing multiple data params passed to link_to in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, haml

I am having trouble accessing multiple data params, passed to a rails link_to, in Jquery. I used to have the following code (embedded HAML):

```
= link_to "Update Setup/Teardown Times", '#', :class => 'update_setup_teardown_link', :data => @event.id
```

and I would access it in Jquery by writing the following:

```
a = $('.update_setup_teardown_link').attr('data');
```

But, if I had multiple data attributes as such:

```
    = link_to "Update Setup/Teardown Times", '#', :class => 'update_setup_teardown_link', :data => {varId: @event.id, bool: true}
```

how would I be able to individually access these data attributes? Any and all help is appreciated. Cheers~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
varId = $('.update_setup_teardown_link').data('varId');
myBool = $('.update_setup_teardown_link').data('bool');
```

See: https://api.jquery.com/data/

OR

```
varId = $('.update_setup_teardown_link').attr('data-varId');
myBool = $('.update_setup_teardown_link').attr('data-bool');
```

See: https://api.jquery.com/attr/